# How do I populate my model in C# MVC view model with data from C# API JSON?

Tags: c#, json, api, viewmodel

I wanted to be able to access my data from anywhere so I made a c# data API that returns json for gets and accepts json for posts. All methods use HTTPResponseMessage as a return type so that I can send back the appropriate responses.

In jquery ajax its a simple thing to use and it works great but when I try to use c# mvc I am completely lost where and how to get the data returned from my API into the data model.

I tried using this in my viewModel. It got the data but then what

```
    static public object GetProfile()
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:50121/api/Profile/1";
        var client = new WebClient();
        var content = client.DownloadString(url);
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jsonContent = serializer.Deserialize<object>(content);
        return jsonContent;
    }

    public readonly object d = GetProfile();
```

Sorry if I am posting this wrong I have not asked questions here a lot.

I just want to populate my model with the json returned from the api call.

Comment: All of these classes are obsolete. I suspect you tried to copy code from various other questions. You can't learn a new language or framework just by copying code. First of all, the question isn't specific to ASP.NET MVC. In .NET in general, you can use `HttpClient` to asynchronously make HTTP requests. The most popular JSON serializer is Json.NET while JavaScriptSerializer was an obsolete serializer created almost 10 years ago. `async/await` can be used in C# too, in fact, JavaScript picked the syntax from C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
var jsonContent = serializer.Deserialize<object>(content);
```

Should be changed to:

```
var jsonContent = serializer.Deserialize<YourModelClass>(content);
```

Where `YourModelClass` is the model that you want to deserialise into.

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize json straight to your model class (`ModelClass` in this example since you did not provide your model class definition).

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; 
static public ModelClass GetProfile()
{
    string url = "http://localhost:50121/api/Profile/1";
    var client = new WebClient();

    //object serialised as json string
    var content = client.DownloadString(url);

    //object deserialised as ModelClass
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelClass>(json);
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Risto... I have a followup couple of questions. I am such a noob... lol

Comment: In Fiddler I can use POST , http://localhost:50121/api/Profile                                 
  with headers            Content-Type:application/json. I am using [FromBody] in the api method so I pass {
"FirstName": "Penny", 
"LastName": "Lonis", 
"EMail": "bam@Loris.com", 
"HeightInches": 67.0, 
"Weight": 140.0, 
"RestingHeartRate": 77, 
"BloodPressure": "130/70", 
"SugarLevel": 100, 
"Goal": "120", 
"Gender": "f", 
"Age": 27
 } to that call. What is the best way to do that from the same MVC project...? And the update is a PUT. How does that happen in MVC?

Comment: And If you have a list of items being returned in a json format [{...},{...},{...}] then you can use: `            public List<UnitOfMeasure>  GetUnitOfMeasure()
            {
                string url = "http://localhost:50121/api/UnitOfMeasure/";
                var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
                var content = client.DownloadString(url);
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var jsonContent = serializer.Deserialize<List<UnitOfMeasure>>(content);
                return jsonContent;
            }
`